# wpf datagrid DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate TextBox HorizontalAlignment

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, datagridtemplatecolumn

I need stretch TextBox in column DataGrid on horizontal. I try make it this way:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Time from"  Width="3*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=TimeOfActions.StartTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=TimeOfActions.IsReadOnly}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

but in result I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdZM9.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to set HorizontalContentAlignment=Center?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `WrapPanel` with `DockPanel`/`StackPanel` and it should work as intended. As a matter of fact, you don't event need a panel following code itself is  sufficient enough:

ItemsSource dataGrid

```
dgDirectoryConditions.ItemsSource = ((ImageItemsViewModel)DataContext).Directories.ConditionsDirectory;
```

ImageItemsViewModel.cs

```
internal class ImageItemsViewModel : DependencyObject
{
     ...
     public ObservableCollection<ConditionsDirectory> ConditionsDirectories { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

ConditionsDirectory.cs

```
public class ConditionsDirectory : BaseDirectory, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ConditionsDirectory()
    {
        DurationOfParking = new DurationOfParking
        {
            IsReadOnly = true
        };
        TimeOfActions = new TimeOfActions
        {
            IsReadOnly = true
        };;
    }

    public TimeOfActions TimeOfActions { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

TimeOfActions.cs

```
public class TimeOfActions : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [JsonProperty("start_time")]
    public string StartTime
    {
        get { return StartTimePrivate; }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EndTime))
            {
                IsReadOnly = false;
            }
            else
            {
                IsReadOnly = true;
            }

            StartTimePrivate = value;
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    private string StartTimePrivate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("end_time")]
    public string EndTime
    {
        get { return EndTimePrivate; }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StartTime))
            {
                IsReadOnly = false;
            }
            else
            {
                IsReadOnly = true;
            }

            EndTimePrivate = value;
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    private string EndTimePrivate { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{StartTime} - {EndTime}";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried without WrapPanel, but it did not lead into success

Comment: @AntonAnpilogov Can you post more code from your view? The code that I posted, is working fine for me.

Comment: @AntonAnpilogov I meant xaml code, not ViewModel code!

Comment: @AntonAnpilogov Not sure what is going on but same code is working for me with .Net 4.5.2 so unless you post your code on github with reproducable problem, my hands are tied.